# Parse api response to XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am hitting an api link with the code below:

```py
import requests
url="https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/web.config?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
data=requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

The sample response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to parse the api response to xml and extract the EnvironmentName, that is Development from this xml. Please assist

Comment: i think you are looking for xpath

Answer (score 0):

you could achive this by simple searching in the string,
like this

```
import re
result = re.search('<EnvironmentName>;(.*)</EnvironmentName>', response)
```

or by searching up a lib that can turn the response into an object and then iterating through its keys

Answer (score 0):

I am listing two packages that can be used to solve your problem.
 I have used a free online `sample XML API` to test your problem and write relevant code.

1. [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict).

This library needs to be downloaded which can be done via pip in the following way `pip install xmltodict`

```
resp = requests.get('http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Traveler?page=6')
dict_of_xml = xmltodict.parse(resp.content)
```

You will get an output like this.

> OrderedDict([('Travelerinformation',
> [OrderedDict([('id', '776'),
> ('name',
> 'Yaamini Yaamini'),
> ('email',
> 'yaaminirangarajan@gmail.com'),
> ('adderes', 'USA'),
> ('createdat',
> '2020-10-08T09:56:30.7263582')])

1. [xmltree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#)

This package does not need any additional installation but usage is somewhat more complex.

You can import the package like this.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
```

To convert the response into the tree you can use.

```
resp = requests.get('http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Traveler?page=6')
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(resp.content)
```

To access the data then you will have to use indices of the response, which is somewhat like this.
tree[4][0](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict).text
You will get an output like this.

> 'Yaamini Yaamini'